# How to disable/remove cache in opencart 3

Tags: caching, opencart-3

I'm working in Opencart vesion 3. I had a problem with cache. I have 2 types of problems.

First one, in Back end if I save(create/edit) anything it does not affect. If I do more than 3 times then only it will work.

Second, in Front end product comparison, wishlist and cart, if I add/delete any product from those it will affect lately or after logout and login.

Can anyone please help me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I found what is the problem here, because of varnish cache the changes takes time to load. After I stopped the varnish it is working fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Kowsalya is correct. The issue was not caused by the caching functionalities of OpenCart. It was caused by the caching configuration of the server.

Due to not being able to resolve this sooner, I also deployed a Presta Shop instance on the server, and also ran in to exactly the same issue. I contacted the hosting company, and the server has NGINX Cache (similar to Varnish cache).

Once switched off, everyone is working as smooth as butter!